# How can i create this layout using Bootstrap grid?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Im designing a Bootstrap template that needs to have a sidebar on the left side (Logo, nav buttons and Contact Info) and Main content on the right side.

The problem is that i need the Contact Info div to go after the Main content div. How can i do this?

This is the code i have so far...but the contact info gets pushed to the bottom of the page (depending on the main content lenght), and i need it to be just after the sidebar links

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-3">
    NAVS LINKS
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-9">
    MAIN CONTENT
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-3">
    CONTACT INFO
   </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I've been trying a lot of different things... I just posted the piece of code that was the closest to what I'm trying to achieve, so people can understand what I'm going for. Also, i simplified the code as much as I could.

Comment: Just *saying* you tried something isn't really helpful. **Show** us what you tried that worked the best and show us that. Did you consider two columns rather than two rows etc. - https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/VVzZRW

Comment: I need the contact info div to be after the main content.

Comment: Then you need to explain **exactly** what it is you are after....because right now...you haven't. That's why we need a demo.

Comment: This is kinda what i need...idk if there is a better or cleaner way to do it https://codepen.io/mrfede/pen/gQxMbK

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want? try removing a row and put the contact info in the same column as the navbar links.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-3">

      <li>HomePage</li>
      <li>Buy</li>
      <li>Sell</li>
      <li>About us</li>
      <li>Location </li>

      <div class="contact">
         CONTACT INFO<br>
         John Smith<br>
         +12346 306434<br>
         johnsmith@internet.com<br>
       </div>
   </div>


   <div class="col-md-9">
       Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Porro sit 
       dignissimos ad, beatae amet dolorem voluptatibus nisi harum ab odit, 
       exomnis nobis facere nesciunt totam inventore rerum quos quaerat. 
       Lorem 
       ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. In saepe 
       provident 
       eligendi ex, eum consequuntur omnis nostrum amet maxime praesentium 
       sunt nulla velit sapiente similique id impedit optio laborum? 
       Distinctio.Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. 
       Porro sit 

   </div>

 </div>
```

if you want the contact info after the main content. just put it in the column as the content but if you want the contact info all across then just do a new row and set the column to 12.

```
   <div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-3">   <--- set this to 12 if you want it all the way across
       CONTACT INFO
     </div>
   </div>
```

Comment: This is kinda what i need...idk if there is a better or cleaner way to do it codepen.io/mrfede/pen/gQxMbK